# AWS CodePipeline: How to get the last succeeded execution for a stage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I have a pipeline with multiple deploy stages (deployments into different accounts). I want to put an approval result programmatically.

The problem comes when there are more then one pipeline executions waiting on approval in parallel.

```
source (Succeeded, commit 3) 
      ↓
build (Succeeded, commit 3)
      ↓
deploy-dev (Succeeded, commit 3) 
      ↓
approve-to-deploy-to-qa (InProgress, commit 3)
deploy-qa
      ↓
approve-to-deploy-to-prod (InProgress, commit 1)
deploy-prod (not run yet)
```

*Example in the picture:* three commits were done, all are run until `dev` (inclusively), only `commit 2` ran thru the `qa` and the stage is now waiting for the next commit (`commit 3`). The stage `prod` was not run yet and it's still waiting on the approval of the very fist commit (`commit 1`).

To approve the last stage (`prod`) programmatically, I have to approve all the commits until the last succeeded commit from the previous stage (`qa`).

Calling `codepipeline.getPipelineState` from AWS JavaScript SDK I get only the current states:

```
{   "pipelineName": "...",
    "stageStates": [
        ...
        {   "stageName": "StagingQA",
            "inboundTransitionState": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "actionStates": [{
                    "actionName": "approval",
                    "latestExecution": {
                        "status": "InProgress",
                        "token": "1d55d6a2-68bb-4e01-83cc-b46101857088"
                    }
                }, {
                    "actionName": "stage-qa",
                    "entityUrl": "..."
                }
            ],
            "latestExecution": {
                "pipelineExecutionId": "d519482d-5a9a-4a6d-b185-3bc3fd5f98e2",
                "status": "InProgress"
            }
        }, {
            "stageName": "StagingProd",
            "actionStates": [{
                    "actionName": "approval",
                    "latestExecution": {
                        "status": "InProgress",
                        "token": "70b5ef16-a912-4b12-a660-be0792a8a70d"
                    }
                }, {
                    "actionName": "stage-prod",
                    "entityUrl": "..."
                }
            ],
            "latestExecution": {
                "pipelineExecutionId": "04b8b2c4-e677-4d1e-a601-f731260ef00a",
                "status": "InProgress"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way how to get the `pipelineExecutionId` for the last **succeeded** execution or at least a list of all executions for a particular stage?

Comment: Can you explain how you're approving commits? CodePipeline has a manual approval action, but it didn't sound like you're using it.

Comment: I actually do, aws sdk has a method to do it programmatically.

Comment: Did you have a look at the listPipelineExecutions and getPipelineState functions? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CodePipeline.html#listPipelineExecutions-property & https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CodePipeline.html#getPipelineState-property Wouldn't inspecting the objects they return help you?

Comment: @Milan Yes, I did. But none of them provides information about executions for **a stage**. `listPipelineExecutions` returns executions only for the pipeline itself and `getPipelineState` just the currect status - is actually in the question meantioned already.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't try it myself, but the docs to `getPipelineState` mention a `stageStates` array in the return object which is a "A list of the pipeline stage output information, including stage name, state, most recent run details, whether the stage is disabled, and other data." so I thought that was it.

Comment: @Milan No problem, thanks anyway. It seems AWS don't provide needed information out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer was updated to reflect an [extended discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188291/discussion-between-aaron-and-ttulka))

CodePipeline is a continuous delivery product, so it's like a pipeline has a stream of changes and the manual approval action acts like a filter. You don't really get to choose which commit to deploy to prod, except by controlling the input to the steam (commits) and the filters (test and approval actions) along the way.

You should place the `deploy-qa` and `approve-to-deploy-to-prod` actions in the same stage like this:

```
source (Succeeded, commit 3) 
      ↓
build (Succeeded, commit 3)
      ↓
deploy-dev (Succeeded, commit 3) 
      ↓
deploy-qa
approve-to-deploy-to-prod (InProgress, commit 1)
      ↓
deploy-prod (not run yet)
```

This lets QA approve exactly what was deployed and tested. Why? Because CodePipeline enforces that exactly one pipeline execution can be in a pipeline stage at any given time. Commit 3 won't be able to enter the QA stage until commit 1 is either approved or rejected.

NOTE: I also removed the `approve-to-deploy-to-qa` action because I suspect you were using it to prevent a newer commit from modifying the QA environment while testing it.

Comment: "Maybe you're referring to a pipeline execution that is between stages" - exactly.

Comment: You can't approve a pipeline execution that is between stages. Are you trying to reject the earlier commit because there's a newer one that's pending? Otherwise it sounds like you should just approve/reject each commit as you encounter them in the stage. There's no guarantee that a pipeline execution between a stage will be the one that eventually enters a stage (if a newer pipeline execution reaches the same point, CodePipeline will supersede the older one and let the newer one enter the next stage).

Comment: Commits 1, 2, 3 were done. Pipeline execution is 3. Qa has 2 as succeeded, 3 as in progress. I want to approve the last succeeded execution (2) of the previous stage (qa) into the prod stage (actually in progress of 1). How to determine the commit 2 as the last succeeded from the previous stage..? Of course, commit 1 must be rejected by prod.

Comment: Why not put the manual approval action in the stage where you deploy and test, so you can be certain that the commit you approve is the one you tested? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48157636/31304 for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Because I have a trigger lambda function approving a whole bunch of pipelines, scheduled by a cron. One central releasing control point.

Comment: Maybe you need more than one manual approval to separate concerns? A manual approval for QA to signoff on a particular pipeline execution and another manual approval in the prod stage to coordinate releases? FWIW, you may want to disable the inbound transition to the prod stage instead of adding a manual approval so you always release the latest pipeline execution (instead of the first one to enter the prod stage holding the lock while waiting for the manual approval to be approved/rejected).

Comment: I have separated function for this. Let's say a function `release-last-qa-tested-commit-into-production` triggers the "manual" approval action for alle the pipelines. Still I don't have the information which commit (execution) was the last succeeded one in the qa stage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188291/discussion-between-aaron-and-ttulka).